# Discord.JS: How to use Web Proxy?

Tags: node.js, proxy, discord.js

I have a Discord bot. I use Node.JS and `discord.js` library. Sometimes, my project's IP gets banned from Discord API. I have to change my project in these cases. `discord.js` library works with web requests. So, I think I can connect to a web proxy and mask my project's IP. Is this possible?

Code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
//Other includes

//Example proxy
const proxyip = '210.210.129.83';
const proxyport = 59623;

client.on('ready', () => {
  //Some on ready code
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  //Commands and other codes
});

client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discord.js uses Websockets to communicate with the Discord API, the problem is that HTTP Proxies will not work for this.

Here is the related Issue
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/489

Answer (score 0):

Use package [node-global-proxy](https://github.com/wwwzbwcom/node-global-proxy)

```
import {Client} from 'discord.js'
import {ProxyAgent} from 'undici'
import {default as proxy} from 'node-global-proxy'

proxy.setConfig({
    http: 'http://localhost:1080',
    https: 'http://localhost:1080',
})
proxy.start()

const client = new Client({
    intents: [],
    rest: {
        agent: new ProxyAgent('http://localhost:1080'),
    },
})

client.login('your-token')
```

Both global proxy and undici proxy agent are necessary.